# why destruction is called?

Tags: c++

I don't know why the destruction of an object in vector is called at the following point of time.

```
class Something
{
public:
    Something() {}
    ~Something()    { cout << "destruction called" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Something> vec;
    Something sth1 = Something();   
    Something sth2 = Something();
    vec.push_back(sth1);
    vec.push_back(sth2);
    vec.clear();
}
```

After I push sth2, destruction for sth1 is called. Why? Shouldn't sth1 be kept in vec[0]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the `vector` has to resize its capacity to be able to store two elements instead of one. It allocates a new buffer, it copies the old buffer to the new one, *removes the old buffer*, and then adds the new object.

Comment: Then what should I do if I want sth1 to be stored in vector until I call `clear()`. I know `reserve()` might help, but what if I don't know the exact capacity?

Comment: @CDBean: You can't have the actual `sth1` object stored in the vector no matter what you do; the vector will always hold on to a copy one way or the other. As I mention in my answer, `push_back()` creates a copy to begin with. You *could* switch to using a `vector<Something*>` if you really want; then only pointers to the original object are being stored (but you have to be careful that they remain valid throughout the lifetime of the vector)

Comment: @CDBean: You can't, and I don't see why you'd want to. (Copies are fine. C++0x adds moves, too.) Why is what's going on bad? If you want to avoid copies, use a smart pointer like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. (Not `auto_ptr`.)

Answer (score 2):

The vector allocates memory (as a contiguous block, i.e. an array) on the fly to hold the objects you put into it. Since it doesn't know in advance how big it will grow to, it grows its capacity gradually as you add more elements to it.

Each time it has to grow to fit a new element, it has to allocate a new array big enough to store everything (typically twice the size as the old array to avoid having to resize too often); then it has to copy all the elements from the old array to the new one. The old array is then freed, destroying the objects it contains.

`vec[0]` *will* contain an object exactly like `sth1`, just not the same object (it will be a copy that was created using the copy constructor during the resize of the vector).

Also note that `push_back()` always copies the element being pushed in (it doesn't keep a reference); this allows the objects it holds to persist in the vector past their lifetime on the stack. So at the end of `main()`, there will be four calls to the destructor: one for each of the two objects in the vector, and one each for `sth1` and `sth2` as they are popped off the stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Something sth1 = Something();
2) Something sth2 = Something();
3) vec.push_back(sth1);
4) vec.push_back(sth2);
5) vec.clear();
```

At 1) you're creating `sth1` on the stack - it's lifetime will be until the stack frame is destroyed as `main()` exits.  The compiler *is permitted* (Standard 12.8.15) to elide the assignment to make the construction equivalent to:

```
Something sth1;
```

But, the compiler is also allowed to follow your code more mindlessly and potentially inefficiently:

```
1a) create a temporary Something()
1a) copy-construct sth1 on the stack, lifetime as per main(), copying the value of the temporary
1c) destroy the temporary
```

Summary: don't bother with the assignment: unlike say C# or Java, objects are constructed implicitly in C++.

At 3) - `vec.push_back(sth1)` can be expected to allocate some memory on the heap, then copy-construct an object therein with the same value as `sth1`.  Note that this is *not* `sth1` itself, but a copy of the value of `sth1` at the time the `push_back` is performed.  Updates to these copies, and updates to `sth1` and `sth2` are then independent.

At 4) the vector may or may not need to resize its heap memory to make space for a copy of sth1: if it does so, then the existing value at `[0]` - which was copy-constructed from sth1 but is *not* actually `sth1`, would be copied to the new memory area then the destructor would be called in the about-to-be-released memory area.

At 5) the *copies* of `sth1` and `sth2` are destroyed

After 5, sth1 and sth2 themselves go out of scope as main exits, and their destructors are invoked.

If you want to see this happening, I suggest you add better trace to your class:

```
struct Something
{
    Something() { std::cout << "Something(this " << (void*)this << ")\n"; }
    ~Something() { std::cout << "~Something(this " << (void*)this << ")\n"; }
    Something(const Something& rhs)
    { std::cout << "Something(this " << (void*)this
                << ", rhs " << (void*)rhs << ")\n"; }
    Something& operator=(const Something& rhs)
    { std::cout << "operator=(this " << (void*)this
                << ") = " << (void*)rhs << '\n'; }
};
```

You can also print `(void*)&vec[0]` after each of the `push_back`s.

Taking a step back from your attempt and looking at whether/how to eliminate copying:

- you can create a `vector<Something*>` then `push_back(&sth1)` and `&sth2`

  - this is fine as long as the lifetimes of `sth1` and `sth2` (which is that of the surrounding scope - here the lifetime of `main()` itself) span the times at which the pointers may be dereferenced
  - following the pointer to the actual `sth1` and `sth2` objects - rather than copies made at the time `push_back()` is used - means that any updates to `sth1` and `sth2` will be visible via the pointers, and updates through the pointers actually affect `sth1` and `sth2`

If you want the lifetime of the objects known to the vector to live beyond that implied by the scope surrounding your stack-based `sth1` and `sth2`, you can:

- allocate `sth1` and `sth2` on the heap ala `Something* sth1 = new Something();`
- keep pointers in the vector

  - if you don't use smart pointers (e.g. boost::shared_pointer), then you'll need to delete each pointer before removing it from the vector or clearing the vector (to avoid memory leaks).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that initialization during declaration *always* uses the copy-constructor (not the assignment operator) but your point about possible inefficiencies still stands

Comment: @Cameron: nope... had a discussion about it on here a week or so ago and consulted the Standard... compiler's free to elide but not required to.

Comment: @Cameron: it's 12.8.15 if you're curious... wording is "is permitted" rather than required/shall etc..

Comment: You're right, here the compiler is allowed to optimize away the temporary object, but if it didn't, the copy constructor would be called, not the assignment operator (12.6.1)